# Solution to the differential equation $y' = (x - y)e^{x - y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've had success solving $y' = e^{x - y}$ and $y' = x e^{x - y}$, but this one has me completely stumped. Substituting $z$ for $x - y$, and after separation, I'm faced with integrating $dz / (1 - z e^z$). Algebraic manipulation gives the integral of $z e^z dz / (1 - z e^z)$, which is similarly out of my league.

[Here's my work so far](https://pastebin.com/wcMUzWGV)

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? Do you have any reason to believe that there is a nice explicit formula for the solution?

Comment: A Youtuber named Sybermath gave the original problem  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AltN6CXMwyc   y' = e^(x - y) and I just kept moving the goal posts.

The sore truth is I have no reason whatsoever to believe there may be some "nice explicit" formula for my integral. I'll definitely settle for way less than that! But I can't help thinking Lambert's W whenever I see z e^z...

Comment: Well, I suspect that you've come about as far one can get. You could perhaps let $w=e^{-z}$ to obtain $x+C=- \int \frac{dw}{w+\ln w}$, but that's very likely a non-elementary integral. You could of course give it a name, say $F(w)$, and then try to say something about the properties of the function $F$, and hence of the solution $w(x)$ (and in turn $z(x)$ and $y(x)$). But it's probably easier to look directly at the ODE for $z(x)$ in order to say something about the solution.

Comment: Just some thoughts.
$$e^yy'=xe^x-ye^x$$
$$e^y=(x-1)e^x-\int ye^xdx$$
$$e^y=(x-1)e^x-\int ((ye^x)'-y'e^x)dx$$
$$e^y=(x-1)e^x-ye^x-\int y'e^xdx$$

Comment: Yeah, the integral of dx / ln x is the so called logarithmic integral.

Comment: Mathematica can't find a solution so it's probably unlikely you will find a closed form solution